# PHPMailer Cron Job Bulk Email Solution

Tags: php

Somehow I managed to create PHPMailer Script with the help of Stackoverflow.

My Script sends emails by fetching list from database.

The issue is I have very big email list. 
I want to send emails with cron job, every hour only 100 mails.
I have set limit by - `select email from emailid LIMIT 0,100`

But the issue is how to Increase 0 to 100 and 100 to 200 each time when script runs?
So script select next 100 emails to send each time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You'll need to offset your query. If you change your sql to the following, it should work.

```
SELECT email FROM `emailid` LIMIT 100 OFFSET 100
```

The offset 100 gets you the "next" 100. Initial would be "offset 0, or just leave the offset command out". You'll have to programmatically increase the offset each time.

If you're interested in advice, I'd suggest adding a "sent" field to the table, and use the following query

```
SELECT email FROM `emailid` LIMIT 100 WHERE `sent` IS NOT NULL
```

Then you just have to flag the sent field after the email is successfully sent.

Comment: Thanks  will try for sure

Comment: is there any difference between LIMIT 100 OFFSET 100 and 100,100

Comment: no difference in 100,100 and typing it out.  essentially just do $x where x is the last value you saved and then keep on moving it up $x, 100 will get the next 100 starting at $x

Comment: Thanks.. i done it via counter value saved in database everytime when script runs it increase value